# Creando un trigger SQL server 2008 ERROR: El objeto no existe

Tags: trigger, sql-server-2008

El siguiente `trigger` me marca el siguiente error al ejecutarlo:

> Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure
>   InsertHystoryOfOrderHasProfiles, Line 1 The object
>   'dbo.OrderHasProfilesOfPayments' does not exist or is invalid for this
>   operation.

Pero esa tabla si existe y tiene ese nombre exactamente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertHystoryOfOrderHasProfiles]
ON [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments int;
DECLARE @idPayment int;
DECLARE @idDriversProfilesOfPayments int;
DECLARE @idOrderTravelInfo int;
DECLARE @conceptDescription varchar(200);
DECLARE @Total decimal;
DECLARE @UOM varchar(20);
DECLARE @Distance decimal(18,0);

SET @idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST ([dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments] AS int)
        FROM [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments] ORDER BY [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments] DESC         
);
-- Para casi todo es necesario el idDriversProfilesOfPayments por lo que es lo primero que obtendremos 
SET @idDriversProfilesOfPayments =
(   
    SELECT  CAST ([dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idDriversProfilesOfPayments] AS int)  
            FROM [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments] 
            WHERE [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments] = @idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments
);

SET @idOrderTravelInfo =
(
    SELECT  CAST ([dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idOrderTravelInfo] AS int)  
        FROM [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments] 
        WHERE [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments] = @idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments
);
-- Cargamos la variable Concept Description
SET @conceptDescription = 
(
    SELECT  CAST (ISNULL (dbo.DistanceConcept.UOM, '')AS varchar(20)) + 
            CAST (ISNULL (LocationFrom.Location,'') AS varchar(50)) + '|*|' +
            CAST (ISNULL (LocationTo.Location, '') AS varchar(50))
            FROM 
            dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments 
            FULL JOIN dbo.DistanceConcept ON dbo.DistanceConcept.idDistanceConcept = (
                SELECT  dbo.DriversPaymentsHasDistance.idDistanceConcept FROM dbo.DriversPaymentsHasDistance WHERE  
                    dbo.DriversPaymentsHasDistance.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments ) 
            FULL JOIN dbo.TrafficLocations AS LocationFrom ON LocationFrom.trafficLocationsID = ( 
                SELECT dbo.LocationConcept.idLocationFrom  FROM dbo.LocationConcept WHERE ( dbo.LocationConcept.idLocationConcept  = ( 
                    SELECT dbo.DriversPaymentsHasLocation.idLocationConcept FROM dbo.DriversPaymentsHasLocation WHERE 
                        dbo.DriversPaymentsHasLocation.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments )))
            FULL JOIN dbo.TrafficLocations AS LocationTo ON LocationTo.trafficLocationsID = ( 
                SELECT dbo.LocationConcept.idLocationTo FROM dbo.LocationConcept WHERE ( dbo.LocationConcept.idLocationConcept  = ( 
                    SELECT dbo.DriversPaymentsHasLocation.idLocationConcept FROM dbo.DriversPaymentsHasLocation WHERE 
                        dbo.DriversPaymentsHasLocation.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments )))
            WHERE (dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = @idDriversProfilesOfPayments)
);
SET @idPayment = 
(
    SELECT  CAST ([idPayment] AS INT ) 
    FROM [DriversProfilesOfPayments]
    WHERE [DriversProfilesOfPayments].[idDriversProfilesOfPayments] = @idDriversProfilesOfPayments
);
SET @UOM = 
(
    SELECT CAST (ISNULL (dbo.DistanceConcept.UOM,'') AS varchar(30))
    FROM dbo.DistanceConcept
        WHERE idDistanceConcept = 
        (
            SELECT dbo.DriversPaymentsHasDistance.idDistanceConcept 
            FROM dbo.DriversPaymentsHasDistance 
            WHERE dbo.DriversPaymentsHasDistance.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = 
            (    
                SELECT idDriversProfilesOfPayments
                FROM dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments
                WHERE dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = @idDriversProfilesOfPayments
            )
        )
);

--inicializamos el valor de @UOM para posteriormente compararlo
-- SI no tiene UOM debe pertenecer su ID a un location
IF @UOM = ''
BEGIN 

    SET @Total = 
    (
        SELECT  CAST (dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.amountBase AS decimal) + 
                CAST (dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.amount AS decimal) 
        FROM 
                dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments 
        WHERE 
                dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = @idDriversProfilesOfPayments 
    );

END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SET @Distance = 
        (
            SELECT CAST ([dbo].[OrderTravelInfo].[distance] AS decimal(18,0)) FROM [dbo].[OrderTravelInfo] WHERE [dbo].[OrderTravelInfo].[OrderTravelInfoID] = 
            (
                SELECT [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idOrderTravelInfo] FROM [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments] WHERE [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments].[idDriversProfilesOfPayments] = @idDriversProfilesOfPayments
            )    
        );
        IF @UOM LIKE '%Mile%'
        BEGIN 
            SET @Total = 
            (
                SELECT  CAST (dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.amountBase AS decimal (18,2)) + 
                    CAST (dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.amount AS decimal (18,2)) * (@Distance/1600.0)  
                    FROM 
                        dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments 
                    WHERE 
                        dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = @idDriversProfilesOfPayments
            );
        END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @Total = 
                (
                    SELECT  CAST (dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.amountBase AS decimal (18,2)) + 
                            CAST (dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.amount AS decimal (18,2)) * (@Distance/1000.0)  
                        FROM 
                            dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments 
                        WHERE 
                            dbo.DriversProfilesOfPayments.idDriversProfilesOfPayments = @idDriversProfilesOfPayments 
                );
            END
    END
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[HistoryOfOrderHasProfiles]
(
    [idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments],
    [idOrderTravelInfo],
    [idPayment],
    [conceptDescription],
    [Total]
)
VALUES
(
    @idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments,
    @idOrderTravelInfo,
    @idPayment,
    @conceptDescription,
    @Total
);
END
```

La Tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderHasProfilesOfPayments]
(
    [idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments][int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idDriversProfilesOfPayments][int] NOT NULL,
    [idOrderTravelInfo][int]NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments] ASC
    )
)ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistoryOfOrderHasProfiles]
(
    [idHistoryOfOrderHasProfiles][int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idOrderHasProfilesOfPayments][int] NOT NULL,
    [idOrderTravelInfo][int] NOT NULL,
    [idPayment][int] NOT NULL,
    [conceptDescription][varchar](200),
    [Total] [decimal],
    [paidDate][DATE],
    [Paid][bit],
    PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
    (
        [idHistoryOfOrderHasProfiles] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: almorejo no te esta reconociendo la base de datos intentaste poniendo **`USE BD;`**  al comienzo de tu trigger?

Comment: Muchas gracias, era todo lo que necesitaba de verdad gracias amigo Gracias era todo lo que nececistaba

Comment: De nada estimado, no olvides seleccionar abajo la respuesta correcta si fue de tu ayuda. saludos ;)

Comment: De hecho andaba buscando la opcion por aqui jajaj soy nuevo, pero ya la encontre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es debido a que no estas llamando a tu Base de Datos, y no la esta reconociendo...

Utiliza:

```
 USE BD;
```

Al comienzo de tu Trigger y se solucionara